# POST to django from iOS app denied 403

Tags: ios, objective-c, django

i have written a django webservice that is suppose to be consumed by my iOS app.
i have manage to get GET requests to work with no particular problem, however the minute i start using POST i get 403. 
I read that it might be the csrf so i tried

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
```

and of course it works!

here is my django view code

```
questionAnswer = request.POST['questionAnswer']
facebookID = request.POST['facebookID']
if Question.objects.get(pk=int(question_id)).meaning == questionAnswer:
    u = User.objects.get(fbid = facebookID)
    u.questions_answered = u.questions_answered + 1
    u.save()
    dictForSend = {'didAnswerCorrect' : 'True'}
    jsonq = json.dumps(dictForSend)
    return HttpResponse(jsonq, content_type='application/json')
else:
    dictForSend = {'didAnswerCorrect' : 'False'}
    jsonq = json.dumps(dictForSend)
    return HttpResponse(jsonq, content_type='application/json')
```

and here is my objective c code

```
NSDictionary *postDict = @{ @"questionAnswer": questionAnswer, @"facebookID": facebookID};
NSString *myDictInJSON = [postDict JSONRepresentation];
NSData *postData = [myDictInJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *URLForSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/checkanswer/%@/") , questionID ];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLForSend];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"%@", JSON);
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

terminal line

```
"POST /questions/checkanswer/1/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2282
```

any idea how to incorporate csrf in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question: [CSRF Token in Django and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485035/csrf-token-in-django-and-ios) I don't think you really need csrf protection in your case.